# Any good alternatives to replace HybridAuth (php) ?

Tags: facebook-login, hybridauth

Any good alternatives to replace HybridAuth (php) ? We tried it, but found it to be too messy for us.

Comment: You can try OpAuth

http://opauth.org/

Comment: >If you are starting new project you shouldn't use HybridAuth.

Comment: which lib should I use if opauth is dead?

Comment: Use an oauth2 client such as https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-client